# Is it possible to upgrade angularjs atttribute directives to use in angular 4?

Tags: angularjs, attributes, upgrade, directive

I've been able to upgrade an angularjs element directive to be used in angular 4.
Here's a sample code:

**[myScores.js]**

```
angular.module('app.components.directives.myScores', [])
.directive('myScores', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      score: '=',
    },
    template: '<div>&gt;&gt;&gt; Your score is {{score}} &lt;&lt;&lt;',
    link: function(scope) {
      console.log("in myScores", scope)
    }
  };
});
```

**[myScores.ts]**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Injector, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { UpgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

@Directive({
  selector: 'my-scores'
})
export class MyScoresDirective extends UpgradeComponent {
  @Input() score: number;

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
    super('myScores', elementRef, injector);
  }
}
```

Notice I'm using UpgradeComponent to upgrade the myScores element directive.
I've tried the same on an attribute directive but got an error.  Is there a way to upgrade an attribute directive?

Here's my attempt of upgrading an attribute directive:

**[makeGreen.js]**

```
angular.module('app.components.directives.makeGreen', [])
.directive('makeGreen', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      console.log("in makeGreen", scope)
      console.log("element", element)
      element.css('color', 'green');
    }
  };
});
```

**[makeGreen.ts]**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Injector, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { UpgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

@Directive({
  selector: '[makeGreen]'
})
export class MakeGreenDirective extends UpgradeComponent {
  @Input() count: number;
  @Output() clicked: EventEmitter<number>;

  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
    console.log("elementRef", elementRef.nativeElement)
    super('makeGreen', elementRef, injector);
  }
}
```

I get an error when loading a page that has something like:

```
<div makeGreen>Text should be green</div>
```

I got this error:

```
Error: Directive 'makeGreen' is not a component, it is missing template.
```

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: @jamiebarrow I gave up on this a long time ago.

Comment: Okay, that's a pity, I guess it's easy enough to re-write the attributes in Angular, but yeah... if I don't have to yet it would be nice :) Thanks anyway for getting back to me

Comment: @jamiebarrow I found a way to expose AngularJS directive in Angular 2 (now 5).  Write an Angular JS component to consume Angular JS directive and upgrade that component in Angular 2.  This means you must run AngularJS 1.5 or higher.

Comment: @Will, please check my answer and let me know if it works by accepting it as answer.

Comment: @Will have you an example of exposing AngularJS directive to Angular 5, I am currently dealing with a closed source third party AngularJS directive that needs to be utilized in Angular 5 component.

UPDATE: I found your example but my ngJS directive is an Attribute directive :(

Comment: @pateketu As of Aug. 2017, I didn't find a way to migrate attribute directives to Angular 4.  It wasn't possible.  Not sure if the Angular team has made this possible since.  I wouldn't hold my breath though.

Answer (score 0):

A Attribute directive can totally have the Input property which can be passed to it from the tag where it's used : For ex:

```
<p highlightThis [highlightColor]="'orange'" [count]="5">Highlighted in orange</p>
```

Also make sure your appModule/SharedModule imports it.

> So the problem i see is with the way you are defining your structural
>   directive. A structural directive doesn't have any template structure
>   attached to it. It applies to any html tag where it's used.

**For you case, i see you are extending the directive with Component class** which is not acceptable to a **Attribute directive** :--

```
MakeGreenDirective extends UpgradeComponent {
```

You should keep the Attribute Directive separate from any Component. For Ex:

```
  import { Directive, ElementRef, Injector, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from 
  '@angular/core';

  @Directive({
    selector: '[highlightThis]'
   })

 export class HighLightThisDirective {
 @Input() count: number;
 @Input() highlightColor: string;
 @Output() clicked: EventEmitter<number>;

 constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {  }

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.decorateMyTag();
 }

 private decorateMyTag(): void {
   console.log("highlightColor", this.highlightColor);
   this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this.highlightColor;
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. You are providing an Angular solution, where the question asks how to upgrade (i.e., using `@angular/upgrade/static`) an AngularJS directive.

Comment: If you care to read through the question, it talks about upgrading to angular 4 and using it there. please check the comments too on question