# Angular hybrid: How to upgrade an attribute directive?

Tags: angularjs, angular, hybrid

I am talking about Angular 1.x directives that do not have a template. Directives with the restrict property set to 'A' (attribute directive).

I can't find any documenten on how to upgrade these directives from Angular 1.x to an Angular 5 directive. Is this at all possible? If so how?

I am using UpgradeModule from '@angular/upgrade/static'. Upgrading and downgrading of regular components and services is working fine.

Comment: What you're referring to is an Attribute Directive, perhaps this link will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45968683/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-angularjs-atttribute-directives-to-use-in-angular-4

Comment: Not really. I don't need a template. I want to manipulate href attributes on existing links.

Comment: The question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . If you have problems with directive *behaviour* and not just that it has attribute selector, then the question should contain all relevant details. Since DOM manipulations should be performed in Angular in very special way, there's a chance that a directive cannot be properly upgraded and should be converted instead.